# Selecting a number randomly with math.random()

Tags: math, random, lua

I want to select a random number within a range, but say number that gets generated is 'x', next time I want the number to be at least x±20. How can I achieve this?

`math.random()` takes only two parameters, So if in turn 1, the number that was selected is 40, in second it should be 50 or more/30 or less, and similarly next time it should be 60 or more/20 or less.

Comment: "math.random() takes only two parameters" It would help if you kindly inform us the programming language

Comment: @leonbloy: I am using Lua, but math.random() is the function like in most of the programming languages(with 1 or 2 ) parameters

Comment: Assuming parameters are the range, I think it's more of an algorithm kind of question. Language should not matter.

Comment: You mean that the next number should be within [x-20;x+20], x being the last number generated?

Comment: Could you specify an overall range? (e.g. only using numbers between 0 and 100)

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing:Actually, my basic concern is to set a background object at random positions with in a range, but objects placed next to each other should have a difference of minimum 15-20.ny idea, how else I might fix this?

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing: Yes, between 0 and 100 would work if that makes any favour to the situation :)

Comment: Ah, so the number should be **at least** 20 away from the previous one, rather than **at most**?

Comment: @jcaron: Yes, exactly

Comment: leonbloy @Maxwell Troy Milton King: Deleted your answers? They were totally awesome, was just about to upvote and realized they have been deleted. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know LUA, so we'll go for pseudocode

```
t = Math.random(0,60);
if (t > last_value - 20)
    t += 40
last_value = t
```

Comment: This works but differs with my solution in two respects: 1: it allows small "cyclic" distances (i.e., it allows x[1]=1 x[2]=99) 2: it does _not_ give a uniform distribution in [0,100].

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a number `x` in the range `[0,L)` such that each one has a (cyclic) distance of at least `d` from the previous (in Java) :

```
  public static double rand1(double L, double d, double x) {
    double y = x +  d + Math.random() * (L - 2.0 * d) ;
    if (y >= L)
      y -= L;
    return y;
  }
```

Disallowing "cyclically" small distances might seem an unneccesary complication, but it's actually a simplification: for one thing, this simple algorithm produces a uniform distribution in `[0,L)`, while the accepted answer does not.

Comment: I like this one as it's more generalized - and better than my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have one "main" object that you are placing randomly between 0 and xMax, and 1 or more "secondary" objects that must then be placed within that same range but at least D away from the main object at mainX, and secondary objects can be as close together from each other if there is more than one of them, then try this:

```
function getRandPosNotTooCloseToMain(xMax, mainX, D)
    assert(2*D < xMax) -- if false then main too "fat"
    local leftLen = mainX - D
    local rightLen = xMax - (mainX + D)
    local leftSideWins = true -- need some default

    if leftLen < 0 then -- can only place it right side of main
        assert(rightLen > 0)
        leftSideWins = false

    elseif rightLen < 0 then -- can only place it on left side of main
        -- nothing to do, because leftSideWins already true

    else -- there is space on either side of main (both leftLen and rightLen > 0), 
         -- so randomly select one side then return random # on that side
        local ratio = leftLen / (leftLen + rightLen)
        if math.random() > ratio then -- right half wins
            leftSideWins = false
        else -- left side wins, this is the default
        end
    end

    if leftSideWins then 
        return math.random(0, leftLen)
    else
        return mainX + D + math.random(0, rightLen)
    end
end
```

This can be tested with:

```
-- test
math.randomseed(os.time())
local numTests = 100000

-- generate a bunch of values for right side always wins: 
for x=1,numTests do 
    local x = getRandPosNotTooCloseToMain(60, 15, 20)
    assert( x >= 15+20, x ) 
end

-- generate a bunch of values for left side always wins: 
for x=1,numTests do 
    local x = getRandPosNotTooCloseToMain(60, 45, 20)
    assert( x <= 45-20, x ) 
end

-- generate a bunch of values for left side always wins: 
for x=1,numTests do 
    local x = getRandPosNotTooCloseToMain(60, 30, 20)
    assert( x <= 10 or x>= 50, x ) 
end

-- if get this far then all tests passed!
print("Passed!")
```

All tests pass. In your case you would set `mainX` randomly via `math.random(0,xMax)`.